# Accumulo client throwing NotServingTabletException

Tags: accumulo

I'm using accumulo in my project (inside jetty), but I'm getting this error when trying to run my code

[client.impl.ThriftScanner] Error getting transport to hostname:9997 : NotServingTabletException

Accumulo itself is up, and I can connect with the shell - create tables, insert and scan.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What can be the reason for NotServingTabletException?

Answer (score 0):

Accumulo TabletServers host Tablets. Each Tablet hosts a portion of the rows for an Accumulo table.

It sounds like there may be some issue where a Tablet is not hosted by a TabletServer. When your application tries to access/update a certain row on this Tablet, the error would be thrown if that Tablet is offline. This situation would not prevent you from being able to perform operations on other tables.

Try to scan the table which your application is accessing and see if an error is thrown. Also, check the Accumulo Monitor or the log files for errors.

Comment: Thank you, but I've scanned each table using the shell scan -t option and it worked with all the tables. Co you have any other idea?

Comment: This is the full exception:   ` DEBUG [client.impl.ThriftScanner] Error getting transport to hostname:9997 : NotServingTabletException(extent:TKeyExtent(table:21 30, endRow:21 30 3C, prevEndRow:null)` 
table "21 30" == "accumulo.metadata"
I have only one slave and when using the shell I was able to scan this table. If it is important - the table has two tablets under the same slave (hostname:9997)

Comment: Do you always see this exception in your client? Or only sometimes? Since you have multiple TabletServers, it's possible that this Tablet was automatically moved from one TabletServer to another (note how this is a DEBUG message, not an ERROR message). This is a naturally happening and transparent operation to you as a user.

Comment: I have only one TabletServer ...And the error happens a few times every second.

Comment: It's just a debug message that's tracking the fact that a tablet doesn't exist at that tablet server for a moment before the client updates it's model and retries. It can happen when tablets migrate, or when tablets split and become new tablets. Yours is probably splitting a lot. You can pre-split your table to prevent this.